# Neuroph - Getting the Neuron Output for Java

Tags: java, neural-network

Using neuroph, I was able to train and test data for image recognition. During testing, the Neuroph Studio was able to show the neuron output for each data sets for example:

Cat: 0.78457.....
Dog: 0.05545.....

How would I output it Java. I don't know what parameters or functions to call in order to display the neuron output.

This is my sample code for testing an image under java:

```
 import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
 import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class ImageRecognitionSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // load trained neural network saved with Neuroph Studio (specify some existing neural network   file here)
 NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.load("MyImageRecognition.nnet"); // load trained neural network saved with Neuroph Studio
// get the image recognition plugin from neural network
ImageRecognitionPlugin imageRecognition = (ImageRecognitionPlugin)nnet.getPlugin(ImageRecognitionPlugin.class); // get the image recognition plugin from neural network

try {
     // image recognition is done here (specify some existing image file)
    HashMap<String, Double> output = imageRecognition.recognizeImage(new File("someImage.jpg"));
    System.out.println(output.toString());
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

However, this is just how to input a test image.

Answer (score 0):

These statements:

```
HashMap<String,Double> output = imageRecognition.recognizeImage(new File("someImage.jpg"));
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

are supposed to output the same (Cat: 0.78457... Dog: 0.05545...) in the java console as in the Neuroph Studio

Make sure that the neural network that you trained using the Neuroph Studio "MyImageRecognition.nnet" is actually placed present in the same directory as this java file. The code looks for it in this statement:

```
 NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.load("MyImageRecognition.nnet");
```